# Linking gnustl_static in multiple native libraries

Tags: android-ndk

I am building 3 native shared libraries lib1, lib2 and lib3. lib1 has dependency on lib2 and lib3. While building these libraries I have specified -lgnustl_static for linking. My question is all the libraries would be having separate copy of "libgnustl_staic.a" library right ? If so would not this create any undefined behaviour in runtime ?

Can anybody suggest when to use libgnustl_static.a and libgnustl_shared.so libraries ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Statically linking a library into multiple shared objects that get loaded into the same executable can cause ODR violations. For identical functions this isn't a problem, but can cause serious problems with global data and static constructors (such as the standard streams in the STL).

It would be better to link the shared STL.

Comment: For me, using `gnustl_static` caused lots of strange errors (pribably due to binary incompatibilities) so the only thing that helped was using `gnustl_shared`. Thanks for helping in the right direction.